# Example request: simple, radical ring

Tags: ring-theory

I'm looking for an example of a ring $R$ (necessarily nonunital) which is simple (in the sense that $R \cdot R \neq 0$ and $R$ has no proper, nonzero 2-sided ideals) and also radical (in the sense that the Jacobson radical $J(R)$ is all of $R$). My only thought so far has been that it suffices to find a simple ring in which all elements are nilpotent. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example of a simple radical ring was constructed in 1961 by E. Sasiada, see:

- E. Sasiada, Solution of the problem of existence of a simple radical ring, *Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci. Ser. Sci. Math. Astr. Phys.* 9 (1961) 257
- E. Sasiada and P. M. Cohn, An example of a simple radical ring, *J. Algebra*
  5 (1967) 373-377.

The problem of the existence of a simple nil ring remained open until 2002, when it was solved by A. Smoktunowicz, see:

- A. Smoktunowicz, A simple nil ring exists, *Communications in Algebra* 30 (2002), no.1, 27-59.

I did some googling and found the following [book](http://books.google.si/books?id=bd-DTiAX7uMC&pg=PA314&lpg=PA314&dq=%22simple+radical+ring%22+sasiada&source=bl&ots=qYVTUfQcQK&sig=9mPJYpHdnm0FIdm2wNhoCUEpmKI&hl=sl&sa=X&ei=wMOUT8mTHofIswa5_q22BA&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22simple%20radical%20ring%22%20sasiada&f=false) in which Sasiada's construction is presented in the form of an exercise.

**Added:** I did some further googling and found the following [article](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-107-03/S0002-9947-1963-0153704-4/S0002-9947-1963-0153704-4.pdf) which might also be of interest.